# LM22678 Unstable output

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am building a voltage regulator with the LM22678-5.

I used TI WE-Bench designer to get the component values needed for the regulator:
[image: regulator values]

The regulator outputs 5V when there is no load however it drops to around 2-3V when a load is connected. Ceramic Capacitors were used for Cin, Cinx and Cbst. Cout is an electrolytic capacitor (35SVPF120M). Below is the PCB layout I used.

[image: PCB Layout]

Note: Although the PCB has the enable pin tied to VIn I just don't connect that pin to the IC and leave it floating as per the datasheet.

This is the output on my DSO:
[image: Voltage Output]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your input voltage doing while the output is doing the fandango?

Comment: The input voltage does the fandango too

Comment: serious layout violation with Vfb, measurement probe errors with ground lead... and poor source impedance

Comment: Try using ac coupled to coax with 50 Ohm terminator on DSO . Your probe noise may be > 10MHz and show dV/dt next time  If V=100mV=LdI/dt and dI is 1A and dt is 50ns what is L?.. Changes are good it is just measurement error from probe ground resonance

Comment: What are you using for an input supply, and how long are the leads?  While the switcher itself could be oscillating like mad, if you've got it hanging off of a high-impedance (or inductive) supply that would also impact stability, particularly without any bulk capacitance at the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for you to make better measurements to measure spike risetime and 50% pulse width (PW50) and spike resonant freq. ....I suspect your biggest issues are;

## a) Wrong L. Shielded Inductor capacitance

This part may have an SRF in the range of the 5th harmonic of 500kHz f_sw and passthru switch spikes from shield shunt capacitance which is in series with output.

Instead, a non-shielded part SRR1208-4R5ML with 30MHz SRF would be better. or next size up 6.5 uH

## b) Scope probe measurements

If not done with calibrated 10:1 probe which gives a flatline on ground test pin. then the probe ground loop antenna effect is giving false measurements.  But since the design cannot handle a load, we do not know the threshold of load regulation error.

### c) test methods

-Measure with 50 Ohm terminated DSO ( AC coupled !!) to ground, for noise-free results then input and output for actual noise with hi-res spurious measurements.
-Measure slow ramped active load ( NPN with triangle wave current) for the cutoff threshold.
-Measure with various step loads ( using NPN active load) to get load regulation error.
-Measure input voltage regulation error ( ensure input supply is adequate)
-Compare with WebBench test results for startup, steady state and BODE plots.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"what I am doing wrong"? - it is likely a sum of small deviations from recommendations of manufacturer. You are not following the recommended layout and details of their component suggestions. You are using non-SMD D1 (inductive leads), the output cap looks too small, input caps are recommended to be at least 2 X 6.8 uF ceramic (webbench comes out with 3 x 22 uF caps, you have only one), and you didn't mention anything about your inductor (pads are too small for a proper inductor).

You need to examine carefully the fundamental current-flow diagram presented in the LM22678 datasheet:

[image]

As the datasheet says:

> Board layout is critical for the proper operation of switching power
>   supplies The most important layout rule is to keep the ac current
>   loops as small as possible

Please trace the current loops as they develop on your PCB, you will find that they are far from optimal.

Addition: here is the WB suggested layout:

[image]

While the BOM lists DO-201 package for diode, the layout shows SMD (funny, pictured in opposite direction). Also, there is no need for massive ground trace coming around the inductor, the capacitance of this fast switching node must be minimized. You also should try to characterise your design not just for "no-load" and "full-load", but try to load it gradually to see, where it starts barfing.

Best thing is to get their reference design, and copy exactly everything.

Comment: The inductor is the Vishay IHLP4040DZER4R7M01. Can you explain what is wrong with this inductor?

Comment: Also webench does not tell me 3x22uF it lists the quantity as 1. And the Through hole diode is the SB10150 which was the part shown on webench

Comment: @jos, the inductor might be OK, but the diode (1.05V) doesn't look like a good Schottky. As I said, a sum of details...

Comment: @jos, my WB shows "Qty.3" on schematics. And diode is B340A. What is your target current?

Comment: my target current is 5A

Comment: @jos what is spike rise time and duration? and resonant frequency

Comment: Also can you explain to me how my PCB layout could be improved. I roughly followed this [link](https://imgur.com/a/hF0f2QL) which is the layout given from WeBench i just ignored Radj, Rfbt Rfbb and Css as they were not in the schematic

Comment: LM22678TJ-5.0/NOPB ‑ 
11V-13V to 5.00V @ 5A. thats my input

Comment: jos ,all the problems need to be verified 1st  if input caps are not 1mOhm what are they.?  hence pls reply what input and output rise time , t_PW50 and resonant f with short ground leads or coax, you may apply 20MHz DSO filter here

Comment: I suspect Shielded inductor has SRF responsible for 2.5MHz ripple which isn't too bad but suggest phase margin is weak , but I am waiting for measurement on spikes